# Correctly populating wpa_supplicant.conf from iwlist scan results

Tags: networking, wpa

I am wondering how I can tell that my *wpa_supplicant.conf* file is both sufficient and valid.

When running

```
iwlist scan
```

outputs

```
ESSID:"wifi"
Protocol:IEEE 802.11bgn
Mode:Master
Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
Encryption key:on
Bit Rates:135 Mb/s
Extra:wpa_ie=jkffi3f04fj043fijfi4jfi4jfi43fj4j232
    Group Cipher : TKIP
    Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
Extra:rsn_ie=3020kffoffef02fefoof4f40f40kf
IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
    Group Cipher : TKIP
    Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
IE: Unknown: 99DKDKEMKFKKKKKEFNEFKE93JJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJDJWDNJNWJDW<S<DWKND
Quality=100/100  Signal level=100/100
```

SSID wifi is the router I wish to connect to which has WPA WPA2 mixed mode with a passphrase password

Therefore I run

```
wpa_passphrase wifi password > /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

which populates my *wpa_supplicant.conf* file

```
network={
        ssid="wifi"
        #psk="password"
        psk=jfijewojfmamkmw2s002d0d023e8r84875fefdoskfslsdf
}
```

However I am wondering whether I should be providing more info here other than just the ssid and psk?